# Automated SQL to identify Contacts to Delete in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Our contact count in Marketing Cloud is increasing quickly and we will start to look at an automated way to delete contacts who no longer exist in CRM. The plan is to compare the All Contacts table with the synchronized DE contact_salesforce and lead_salesforce. If the Contact exists in All Contacts but does not exist in the synchronzed DEs then we can assume that the contact has either been deleted or merged in CRM and we can then proceed with the delete contact in Marketing Cloud.

In order to accomplish this, we will need to query the All Contacts in Marketing Cloud. I know we have the _subscribers data view but in this case, we want to pick up all contacts not just contacts who have been sent an email.

Can you advise on how to accomplish this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at using new flows? as far as point click goes, Flow is the only one that can help you delete records where you can also loop through it. Only limitation would be, if you do use scheduled flow you need to mention batch records since in your case you need to do the activity with all contacts always, it would be worth using apex batch.

Comment: Thanks EasyE , this answers the how to do the delete in Marketing Cloud but the identification of the contacts who should be deleted is where I need the most help.

Comment: Thanks apple123, I need to delete in Marketing Cloud and not CRM. The delete in Marketing Cloud should happen after contacts are merged or deleted in CRM.

Comment: @Paul Understood. can you use afterDelete to mark contacts that are deleted and then in your process to delete it in Marketing cloud, use that boolean (in a batch or something).

Comment: `WARNING` customers that delete contacts using the GDPR functionality will render the SDKs unable to communicate with the Marketing Cloud servers.  You need to be very, very careful to ensure that you're not deleting contacts that are still valid.

Comment: Thanks @BillMote, so if a contact is deleted and is included in Mobile Push which uses the SDK, that contact will not receive a push notification which is expected or is it the whole connectivity with SDK that gets impacted ?

Comment: As of 20210511 the only way to delete a contact is through the GDPR functionality.  Because of this, all communication to/from the SDK is terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have MobileConnect, you can create a filtered list of All Contacts. Then in your automation, use the Refresh Mobile Filtered List activity to refresh the list. You'll then be able to query the SubscriberKey from your list (the field to query is called SubscriberKey, but I believe the list contains includes all contacts, not just email contacts). To automate the actual deletion, you'll need to run a script activity once you've identified contacts to delete.